Building GCC found no GLIBCXX in libstdc++.so
I am now building GCC 12.1.0 on CentOS 7.4, and I'm surprisingly find that there are no GLIBCXX at all in the built libstdc++.so.6. However, older version like 5.5.0, 7.4.0 and 9.3.0 would not run into the issue. The strings command give the following output.
# strings /data/share/apps/gcc/12.1.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH

and
# strings /data/share/apps/gcc/9.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
...

While GLIBC seems to be normal, with GLIBC_ no more than 2.17.
I tried to build GCC 12.1.0 according to the procudure on official document directly. And I also tried to use newer GCC version (like the built GCC 9.3.0) to build the 12.1.0 and facing the same situation.
Then I tried to add --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible and seemed to be useless.
Some older versions like 10.1.0 also face the issue.
Because of usage on HPC system, it would not be a good idea to install devtool on remote hosts one by one and, in my opinion, manually compilation might be the easiest way.
So what happened and how could I deal with it?

Well, after adding binutlils 2.41 to dependency, the issue seems to be solved.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
